# Understanding Rails default_url_options

Tags: ruby, configuration, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a project, where runs ok in production([Linux + Apache](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application_including_rails_gt_3))

But I develop with two computers with WEBrick, one is Mac (localhost:3000) and another is a Linux through another IP (ex: http://145.xx.xx.20:3000)

To use `url_for` (previous `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`) I need to configure  in `development.rb`:

```
  routes.default_url_options[:host]="http://145.xx.xx.20"
  routes.default_url_options[:port]="3000"
```

And If I put the same configuration in `production.rb` It works too in production database with WEBrick `rails s -e=production`, that's perfect to develop with production database.

I have two questions:

In development, ¿ How I can make `url_for()` returns me the correct url, depending if I'm on one computer or another? ht..p:/localhost:3000 or http://145.xx.xx.20/:3000

- Added after izumeroot response: How can I get the request.env (Controller) or Rack::Request.new(env) within  config/development.rb o  config/production.rb? to get the host?

In Apache environment (real production), it appears that ignores `production.rb`, because always go fine. http://real.ip.production/ Why?

Answer (score 1):

I use this for correct domain and port in emails (development mode)

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => lambda { |env| Rack::Request.new(env).host }, :port => 3000 }
```

I think  you need use some think like this, but for  **routes.default_url_options**

Comment: I supose you put this code in a controller. I had  routes.default_ur... in config/production.rb and development.rb, and there it doesn't work, when I use  Rails.application.routes.url_for(:controller...  it crash: NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `match' for #<Proc:0x9406894>.

Comment: How can I get the request.env (Controller) within config/development.rb o  config/prodution.rb? that's the question

Comment: No, I use my code in config/development.rb. What code do you try?

Comment: Also, why need you use **url_for** instead url-helpers like **users_url**, **new_user_url and** etc?

Comment: I use url_for in a Model, to populate a text saved in a table (my emails are saved in bbdd...) and I serve to users a link for autoling

Comment: So, did you try my code with labda?
Is there problem send ready url from controller to model?
model_name.save_email(current_url).

Comment: I have: `routes.default_url_options = { :host => lambda { |env| Rack::Request.new(env).host }, :port => 3000 }` in config/development.rb, and when I use url_for in a model, it crash

Comment: Is not the same routes.url_for() than action_mailer.url_for(). for me it crashes to if I call Rails.application.routes.url_for() in a controller

Comment: Since now, the only solution I found is adding code in a before_filter controller. adding something like ` Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = {:host => request.host_with_port}`